Importing multiple dependencies that have @CucumberContextConfigurations for leveraging their step definitions causes `CucumberBackendException`
I've been battling this issue for 2 days, but out of options I guess. I'm not a guru in Cucumber or Gradle, but since my area of expertise is close (Java/Spring/Maven), I've been working on updating multiple Gradle-based Cucumber projects to the latest versions of used frameworks. One of the issues I faced was io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration. I resolved it by adding one such class per each of my projects like this:
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:cucumber.xml")
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration
{

}

These configs were added to the same packages where step definitions reside, otherwise it was not visible since step definitions are specified via glue property of @CucumberOptions annotation in the test runner.
So it all worked in those projects until I started combining those together as dependencies. Imagine this: project A has some step definitions with its CucumberSpringConfiguration class defined. Project B has its own step definitions with its own CucumberSpringConfiguration class defined in the same package as its step definitions. Now project C imports A and B as its dependencies to leverage step definitions for an end to end test. And here the problem occurs:
io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Glue class class com.projectA.core.stepdef.CucumberSpringConfiguration and class com.projectB.core.stepdef.CucumberSpringConfiguration are both (meta-)annotated with @CucumberContextConfiguration.
Please ensure only one class configures the spring context

What would be a way to resolve this? I thought about excluding those from the classpath like this (in build.gradle), but it did not work out:
tasks.withType(Test) {
    excludes = ['**/CucumberSpringConfiguration**']
    doFirst {

        // Get the current classpath
        def classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath

        // Filter out the specific class file I want to exclude
        classpath = classpath.filter { file ->
            !file.absolutePath.contains("CucumberSpringConfiguration")
        }

        // Set the modified classpath
        setClasspath(files(classpath))
    }
}

I tried to move that CucumberSpringConfiguration in dependency projects out of that step definitions package, but since it's used in glue parameter of @CucumberOptions annotation in the test runner, it complains about necessity of having one.
Help from Cucumber/Gradle gurus is much needed here! Thank you very much in advance!

In your dependencies only include the step definitions and xml files, but not the runner classes and @CucumberContextConfiguration annotated classes. Then your project C won't see the project specific test code from A and B. You can do that by using src/main and src/test.

You'll also want to give the xml files unique names so C can use them again.

@M.P.Korstanje, as I understand it, @CucumberContextConfiguration annotated classes should be among step definitions specified in "glue" parameter, otherwise I get io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration.
Also, could you please elaborate on including only step definitions and xml file as dependencies in Gradle? Giving an example would be fery helpful!

Your understanding is correct. Project A, B and C each need a runner class and a class annotated with @CucumberContextConfiguration on the glue path. But they should not share those classes with other projects. In the simplest terms, you are making a java library. You want to ship the production code kept in src/main but not the test code kept in src/test. So the glue code goes into main, and the runner and annotated class into test. If you follow the standard project layout of Gradle this work automatically.

Providing a working example is a bit too much work, but I do believe Gradle provides quite extensive documentation.

Thank you, it makes perfect sense since CucumberSpringConfiguration really belongs to the runner (config) part as you rightfully noted and my runner is under test source folder. I should've thought about it myself! I moved CucumberSpringConfiguration to the test source folder (under the same package com.projectA.core.stepdef) in projectA. Glue parameter of @CucumberOptions has path corresponding to that package (/com/projectA/core/stepdef). And it all now works like a charm! Please add an answer and I will mark it as accepted one. Thank you again for your help, you saved my day! :)

Project A, B and C each need a runner class and a class annotated with @CucumberContextConfiguration on the glue path. But they should not share those classes with other projects.
Because you are making a library, the production code kept in src/main is shared but not the test code kept in src/test. So the glue code goes into src/main, and the runner and annotated class into src/test.
